# How to get this name of Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, san

[image]

I was using [san](https://baidu.github.io/san/doc/api/) (a frame alike `vue`) 
And I `console` a node like this.Can you please tell me what is `ce` and how can I get the value of it.

I think it is a nickname of the node tree.

Thx.

Comment: `ce` is the name of a variable. The value of this variable is an object, the object you are displaying in the developer tools. You can get values from this object just like any other, e.g.`ce.content` is an empty string in your example. However, it looks like the code may have been run through a minifier, so the variable named `ce` here may have a different name in the source.

Comment: But how can I get this value?

Comment: What did you `console.log`? Can you include that code as well